# solidity remix calling one contract from another when the contracts are in two different files

Tags: solidity

The following solidity code works as expected

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Another {
    uint public balance;
    function sendToAnother() public {
        balance += 10;
    }
}

contract Test {
    function send(address another) public {
        Another(another).sendToAnother();
    }
}
```

I want to move the Another contract to a separate file. So now I have the following two files:

```
//Test.sol
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Another {
    function sendToAnother() public pure returns (uint);
}

contract Test {
    function send(address another) public pure {
        Another(another).sendToAnother();
    }
}
```

And

```
//Another.sol
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Another {
    uint public balance;
    function sendToAnother() public {
        balance += 10;
    }
}
```

In remix, I am then doing the following:

1. Deploying `Another` Contract from `Another.sol`, and copying its address.
2. Deploying `Test` Contract from `Test.sol`
3. Invoking `send()` from `Test` Contract with the address of the `Another` contract deployed in step 1

At this stage, I am getting the following error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
call to Test.send errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, you need to add an import for the contract you are accessing.

```
//Test.sol
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

import "./Another.sol";

contract Test {
    function send(address another) public  {
        Another(another).sendToAnother();
    }
}
```

and

```
//Another.sol
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Another {
    uint public balance;
    function sendToAnother() public {
        balance += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: followup question : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63433/remix-ganache-cannot-call-one-contract-from-another

Answer (score 0):

This is because your ABIs don't match. You can do what Felix suggested in another answer, or you can fix the ABI. The actual function in Another.sol doesn't define a return value, but version defined in Test.sol says it returns a uint256, when it doesn't. Newer versions of Solidity validate the return data size, so remove the return value from the Another in Test.sol and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that the function signatures diverge, as mentioned by user *flygoing*. There is no `pure` keyword in the first code snippet (the one mentioned as working) either, even though it is apparently acceptable when declaring in `Test.sol`.
In `Test.sol`, `sendToAnother` signature is: `function sendToAnother() public pure returns (uint)`, while in `Another.sol` it is defined as `function sendToAnother() public`.

The main issue, however, is that `sendToAnother` function, and consequently the `send` function, cannot be declared as `pure` as they modify state **[1]**.

The equivalent working code would then be:

```
//Test.sol
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Another {
    function sendToAnother() public;
}

contract Test {
    function send(address another) public {
        Another(another).sendToAnother();
    }
}
```

and the other contract, unchanged:

```
//Another.sol
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Another {
    uint public balance;
    function sendToAnother() public {
        balance += 10;
    }
}
```

Using the `import` statement, as mentioned by user *Felix Dolderer*, instead of declaring `contract Another` in `Test.sol` file, also works, but it is not a requirement.

**[1]** Pure Functions. https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/contracts.html#pure-functions

Stay super!

/Javi