# Remix + Ganache - Cannot call one contract from another

Tags: remix, ganache

I have an innocent looking contracts that work painlessly in Remix. Test contract can easily call Another if I use JavaScript VM in Remix.

I also have ganache-cli running on port 7454. If I connect Remix to ganache-cli, each of these contracts work well individually. But I cant call Another from Test. Remix console says `transact to Test.send errored: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

My contracts look like:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Another {
    uint public balance;
    function sendToAnother() public {
        balance += 10;
    }
}

contract Test {
    function send(address another) public {
        Another(another).sendToAnother();
    }
}
```

One suspicion I have is - am I picking up the address of the Another contract correctly? I am copying it from Remix's `Deployed Contracts` tab.

Edit: Odd enough, it works well on Ropsten Test Network! Could it have to do something with running out of gas. Unlikely, since remix shows around 100 Ether on the account.

[Submitted a Bug to Ganache trufflesuite/ganache-core](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/issues/242)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest to try with a different version of ganache, perhaps it is a regression. I've several issues with odd regresions intruced between versions.

Comment: Any ideas on how to find archived versions of Ganache?

Comment: You can use npm to install old versions, for example to install v6.1.8 use `npm install -g ganache-cli@6.1.8`. To see available versions consult https://www.npmjs.com/package/ganache-cli, in the versions tab.

Comment: @Amarsh I can confirm this doesn't work with Ganache too. Remix works fine. Submit bug to Ganache team https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues

Comment: thanks @ZulhilmiZainudin . The bug is reprted at https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/issues/242

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to me.

I was able to find a solution, but this only works if you call sendToAnother() from Another first, and then call it from Test.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Another {
    uint public balance;
    function sendToAnother() public returns (bool success) {
        balance += 10;
        return true;
    }
}

contract Test {
    function send(address another) public {
        Another(another).sendToAnother();
    }
}
```

Even though this solution works, I'm not 100% clear as to why it worked for the Javascript VM and not for Ganache.
It looks like while using Remix, Ganache is searching for a return first, thus the immediate revert being thrown. My guess is it's a bug, but would love to hear some more ideas/theories if anyone has them.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work :( I am attaching a screenshot with the original post. Thanks for the effort

Comment: I went back to do some more testing. This only works when you call `sendToAnother()` from Another first, and then call it from Test. Looks like a bug to me - Updating my answer.

Comment: Filed at github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/issues/242 ... perhaps others are facing similar issues